# Update database using DataGridView (selected row)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, readonly

I'm building a small C# app, for myself and I'm not that much into programming (beginner) and I'm asking for your help. I am using a `DataGridView` , which is read only, to display some records from a `database` (MSSQL), which works fine. I would like to update the database without making the `DataGridView` editable or by editing values through textboxes (all I could find so far). Is there any possibility to update the `database` based on the selected row? Thanks.

Comment: If the DataGridView is readonly, you don't want to use textboxes to change the row, how do you plan to change that row? If you don't change the row you don't need to update anything.

Comment: @Steve - there is a boolean column in the `database` and I would like to update from `True` to `False`, based on the selected row...

Comment: Use SelectionChanged event of the datagridview to call a query? That should be the best way if you are updating only one column.

Comment: Still totally unclear. So there is a column with a boolean value of (IE False) , now what you want to do with the underlying row? Change the value to True? If yes when? Just clicking on the row should change the value to its opposite (True->False, False->True)? Or do you want to have a button to click and invert the value of the selectedrow?

Comment: @Steve - No. Only updating from `True` to `False` by clicking on a button.

Comment: Use `DataGridView.CurrentRow` in the `Button_Click` method.

Answer (score 1):

My case is same that DataGrid is readonly, not editable and utilizing the selected values through below way,

This is not WinForm code but WPF code and you might follow the idea. Why don't you use WPF than WinForm?
Hope this helps..

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 if (yourdatagrid.SelectedItem != null)
  {
   object item = yourdatagrid.SelectedItem;
   string record= (yourdatagrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;

   // your SQL Update code with selected values here
   // and you need to re-load values from database to DataGrid to be shown updated
  }
}
```